# Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I want to generate a node that can be removed by clicking, i can generate it and some times even click it and remove it, but then it comes back or it starts to make strange movements until the game crashes. This is what appears in the console:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'cuadradoRojo' (164 x 164)] position:{362.90328979492188, 790.66668701171875} size:{54.666667938232422, 54.666667938232422} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183dea59c 0x19453c0e4 0x183dea4dc 0x18841c0fc 0x1000e73d0 0x1000e7d34 0x1000e8038 0x1000e8d44 0x18840e9ac 0x18840bfd8 0x188409038 0x188435fd8 0x100364a9c 0x187f3d280 0x187f3d118 0x184f398d0 0x183d8d5e4 0x183da2200 0x183da2160 0x183da00e0 0x183ccd0a4 0x18ce675a4 0x1885feaa4 0x10010f0c4 0x10010f104 0x194baaa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I don't have exerience programming so i don't know how to interpretate that. Here is my code, hope you can help. Thanks.

```
import SpriteKit
enum BodyType : UInt32 {

    case colorAzul  = 1
    case circuloAzul = 2
    case colorRojo = 4
    case circuloRojo = 8
    case cuadrado = 16

}
class Scene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

    var cuadradoRojo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cuadradoRojo")
    var lastYieldTimeInterval:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
    var lastUpdateTimerInterval:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
    var velocity:CGFloat = 0
    var gameOver = false
    var score = 0

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    }
    func addAlien(){
        cuadradoRojo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: cuadradoRojo.size.width)
        cuadradoRojo.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        cuadradoRojo.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.cuadrado.rawValue
        cuadradoRojo.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.colorAzul.rawValue | BodyType.colorRojo.rawValue
        cuadradoRojo.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

        var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        if gameOver == false{


            let minX = cuadradoRojo.size.width/2
            let maxX = self.frame.size.width - cuadradoRojo.size.width/2
            let rangeX = maxX - minX
            let position:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) % CGFloat(rangeX) + CGFloat(minX)
            cuadradoRojo.position = CGPointMake(position, self.frame.size.height + cuadradoRojo.size.height)
            addChild(cuadradoRojo)

            let minDuration = 3
            let duration = Int(minDuration)
            actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -cuadradoRojo.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))
            cuadradoRojo.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))

        }



    }

    func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate:CFTimeInterval){
        var randomNum = Double(arc4random_uniform(20))
        var xTime = ((randomNum / 20) + 0.4)
        lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
        if (lastYieldTimeInterval > xTime){
            lastYieldTimeInterval = 0
            randomNum = Double(arc4random_uniform(25))
            addAlien()
        }

    }
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        var timeSinceLastUpdate = currentTime - lastUpdateTimerInterval
        lastUpdateTimerInterval = currentTime
        velocity = CGFloat(score*3)

        if (timeSinceLastUpdate > 1){
            timeSinceLastUpdate = 1/60
            lastUpdateTimerInterval = currentTime
        }
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -velocity)
        updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate)


    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.cuadradoRojo{

                cuadradoRojo.removeFromParent()
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before calling addChild(cuadradoRojo), call cuadradoRojo.removeFromParent(), so you don't add it twice to its parent, SKScene

Comment: Thank you very much this has solved the problem but the node keeps on doing weird things it goes before i can click it and the it never comes, i mean i can just generate once. Do you know why?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What should the node do exactly on the screen?

Comment: it should just fall vertically.

Comment: It kinda does that. Should it fall from the top of the screen when it spawns?

Comment: Yes it falls from the top of the screen but suddenly it goes and some times it comes back moving in a random way. Before it disappears it moves correctly. The biggest problem is that the node goes from the screen and  then it doesn't come back again not even when it is supposed to appear again.

Comment: Try to move the addAlien() method call to touchesBegan, and set the alien's y-position to top of the screen whenever y-position < 0 or it is touched